# Show an image next to a result from MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling a table from a MySQL database, using PHP.

This is roughly the code I'm using, obviously I've got more columns, but this is the demo version of the code.

As you can see, the code is ordered by the Sales Name. Now what I want to do is, show a little icon next to the top ten sellers based on the Sales Count.
So, if a Sales Count is one of the top ten figures, it must show a little image next to it's name.

Can this be done?

```
<?php
  // Get all the data from the "sales" table
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY SalesName") or die(mysql_error());  
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  echo "<tr> <th>Sales Name</th> <th>Sales Count</th> </tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['SalesName'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['SalesCount'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
  } 
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it:

```
    <?php
      $item_no=1    // number of current items
      // Get all the data from the "sales" table
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY SalesCount desc SalesName ") or die(mysql_error());  
      echo "<table border='1'>";
      echo "<tr> <th>Sales Name</th> <th>Sales Count</th> </tr>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        echo "<tr><td>"; 
        if($item_no <= 10){
            echo 'your image here';
            $item_no++;
        }

        echo $row['SalesName'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['SalesCount'];
        echo "</td></tr>"; 
      } 
      echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY SalesName") or die(mysql_error());
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM sales ORDER BY SalesCount DESC limit 10") or die(mysql_error());
while($savedResult = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
  $topten[] = $savedResult[0];
}
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Sales Name</th> <th>Sales Count</th> </tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result )) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['SalesName'];
    if (in_array($row['id'],$topten)) {
        echo '<img src="star.gif"/>';
    }
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['SalesCount'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This sends a second query which gets the `id` column for the top ten orders by sales count. I then store these `id`s in an array (`$topten`). While in the loop to display the table I check if the line being processed is in the top ten array - if so add a star !

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
<?php
  // Get all the data from the "sales" table
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY SalesName") or die(mysql_error());
  $topTen = mysql_query("SELECT SalesName FROM sales ORDER BY SalesCount LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());  
  $topTenArray = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
      $topTenArray[] = $row['SalesName'];
  } 
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  echo "<tr> <th>Sales Name</th> <th>Sales Count</th> </tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['SalesName'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['SalesCount'];
    if(in_array($row['SalesName'],$topTenArray){
        echo "<img src.... />";
    } 
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
  } 
  echo "</table>";
?>
```